# Exponential families: convergence in distribution implies convergence in mean?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, measure-theory

Various results in statistics are about asymptotic distribution of certain estimators. For example, central limit theorem states that

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\theta}_{\text{MLE},n} -\theta_0\right) \overset{d}\to \mathcal{N}(0,V)$$

We also have

$$ 2 \left[\ell\left(\widehat{\theta}_{\text{MLE},n}\right) - \ell(\theta_0)\right] \overset{d}\to \chi^2_1 $$

where $\ell$ is the log-likelihood.

Of course, for them to hold, we will need some assumptions. Common assumptions include $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE},n} \overset{p}\to \theta_0$, $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE},n}$ is a zero for the derivative of log-likelihood, minimizer of log-likelihood is unique and an interior point of the support, third order derivative of log-likelihood $\ell \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n, \theta \right)$ is dominated by some function, etc.

**My question is**, assuming all those assumptions hold (sometimes it's called the Classical Conditions, like in Van der Vaart), when can we go from "convergence in distribution" to "convergence in expectation"?

As an example where statisticians make such conclusion, here is an excerpt from the book Akaike Information Criterion Statistics:

> ... Thus we have $\ell^*(\theta_n) = \ell^*(\theta^*) - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n} (\theta_n - \theta^*)^T J_* \sqrt{n} (\theta_n - \theta^*) + o_p(1)$. (there is no $o_p(1)$ in the original text).
>
> From asymptotic normality of MLE and relation between normal r.v. and chi-square r.v., $n (\theta_n - \theta^*)^T J_* (\theta_n - \theta^*)$ is asymptotically distributed as chi-square with $K$ degrees of freedom.
>
> Consequently, since mean of the chi-square r.v. is $K$, it is approximately true, for large $n$, that
>
> $$\mathbb{E}[ \ell^*(\theta_n)] = \mathbb{E}[ \ell^*(\theta^*)] - \frac{K}{2}$$

In the last step, author is saying something like "since $X_n\overset{p}\to W$, $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \to \mathbb{E}[W]$", which is not true in the most general cases. But what about in this case?

Comment: Case by case, you check uniform integrability or concoct a dominating function.  It's better to arrange your life so you don't actually need convergence in mean results.

Comment: @kimchilover So there is no worked-out theory on this? If that's true than it's quite surprising.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Sometimes one is lucky and some standard trick works fine, sometimes you have to fight.

Comment: Your first two results hold for some families of distributions, but are not universally true. And the central limit theorem is about the distribution of a mean or of a sum, and MLEs are not always means or sums.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have rewrite my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I stand by my first comment's second sentence.  I'd add: yes, its typically an unjustified and possibly false step, but what are the downstream consequences?  Maybe the author does not actually *use* the claimed expectation equation but only some consequences of it, such as (say) the median of this is exceeds the median of that, or the truncated expectation of this exceeds the truncated expectation of that.

Comment: @kimchilover As far as I can tell there is no downstream consequence. Author is deriving how we get Akaike information criteria, and he justifies the definition of AIC using that equation. Namely, AIC is asymptotically unbiased estimator of kl-divergence

Comment: If you redefine "asymptotically unbiased" to mean something like "has a limit distribution whose expectation is 0", your troubles go away.

Comment: @kimchilover I am confused. I am not _redefining_ the term "asymptotically unbiased". I am just trying to understand the quoted part of the text.

Comment: I was not *accusing* you of redefining the term but *advocating* that you do.

Comment: @kimchilover Ah I see what you mean. But the way the author put it (as well as many other online  sources) makes me think that we're talking about convergence in mean here. That's why I'm posting this question...

Comment: The title of your question mentions exponential families.  That might simplify some of the analytical issues.  It's true that, eg, that not only does $N(\theta,1)$ converge in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $\theta\to0$ but also in mean, because the mgf is continuous in $\theta$.